# rewrite rule for canonical link to pdf

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I am trying to set a canonical link for a pdf file using rewrite 2.0. Is this possible?

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Returnable Crate PDF" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="/returnablecrates/Crate_FAQs.pdf" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="https://www.somecompany.com/ rel="canonical" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: what does the pdf have to do with this? a url just points at SOMETHING. what that something actually is, is pretty much irrelevant. if you can build a canonical url to point at "foo", you should be trivially able to build a canonical url to point at "bar".

Comment: the pdf is important because you cant add a <link> tag to a pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Google Search Engine Console:

> rel=canonical  tag   Only works for HTML pages, not for files
>   such as PDF. In such cases, you can use the rel=canonical HTTP header.

One solution I know of --see the accepted answer for how to handle PDF and image files using a canonical header .php file. [Canonical Header Links for PDF and Image files in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637238/canonical-header-links-for-pdf-and-image-files-in-htaccess)